# Value of Numeric control in script, LabView

Tags: labview

I am trying to control a KEITHLEY 2612A SourceMeter using labview. I have installed the appropriate drivers and I managed to connect to the instrument using VISA. Currently I am just experimenting with the scripting language, which the instrument uses.

Is it possible to use a Numeric Controller - a Knob for example - and use its value in the script to be loaded to the instrument? I don't have enough reputation points to add images.

**EDIT**

```
ON = 1
OFF = 0

function hello()
    display.clear()
    display.setcursor (1,7)
    display.settext ("DONE :)")
end

smub.reset()
smub.source.output = ON

--Set the measurement integration time
smub.measure.nplc = 1
smub.measure.delay = 0.05

--Configure the reading buffers
smub.nvbuffer1.clear()
smub.nvbuffer1.appendmode = 1
smub.nvbuffer1.collecttimestamps = 1
smub.nvbuffer1.collectsourcevalues = 0
smub.nvbuffer1.fillmode = smub.FILL_ONCE

for i = 0, 0.5, 0.01 do
    smub.source.levelv = i
    reading  = smub.measure.i (smub.nvbuffer1)
end

delay(5)

hello()

smub.source.output = OFF

delay(1)

display.clear()
display.setcursor(1,1)
display.settext(string.format("%g", smub.nvbuffer1[1]))
delay(5)
display.clear()
display.settext(string.format("%g", smub.nvbuffer1[50]))
```

Block diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/siZAa.png
Front panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9MVF.png

Comment: Yes, you will need to "write" the control to the instrument using SCPI commands defined in documentation for the instrument.

Comment: Upload the image somewhere else and provide a link.

Comment: Sure you can, please add the code you are using so we can help.

Comment: @WG-
I edited the question adding the script and captures from the front panel and block diagram. How can I add a knob on the system so that I can choose which buffer element to print according to th value of the knob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LabVIEW has [standard string manipulation](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/glang/string_functions/) primitives, and you can accomplish your goal by using string substitution: place a sentinel string in your script and replace it with the value from the knob.

### Example

Here, I've used `__BUFFER_NUMBER__` as a unique string in the *Script Format* input terminal. LabVIEW searches for that string and replaces it with the knob's current value.

[image]

#### Block diagram

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to put the stop button and knob outside the while loop and still get the new value whenever the knob rotates or the button is pressed? I tried doing it with loop tunnels their values remain constant.

Comment: Yes, see the *Communicating with running subVIs* section in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010792/labview-creating-subvis-makes-the-block-diagram-expand) -- use a queue and the producer/consumer pattern. A loop and a subVI have the same run-time constraints -- values on their input terminals cannot change while they are executing.

Answer (score 0):

You add the knob control, wire the value to the number-to-string VI (http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/glang/number_to_fract_string/
), and wire that to the "Search and replace string VI" (http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/glang/search_and_replace_string/) you search for the value in the script that you want to replace.